# When graph export to html, plotly on_click event doesn't work

Tags: python, graph, onclick, plotly

I am in trouble with plotly on_click event. When i work with jupyter notebook, the click event works succesfully.

But when i exported to html, on_click event doesn't work, i can not open the url such as work in notebook.

Code:

```
fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 0].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 0].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 0].Z,
    name='Cluster 0',
    mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 1].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 1].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 1].Z,
    name='Cluster 1',
    mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 2].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 2].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 2].Z,
    name='Cluster 2',
    mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 3].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 3].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 3].Z,
    name='Cluster 3',
    mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 4].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 4].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 4].Z,
    name='Cluster 4',
    mode='markers')
fig.add_scatter3d(
    x=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 5].X, y=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 5].Y,
    z=df_pca3d[df_pca3d["labels"] == 5].Z,
    name='Cluster 5',
    mode='markers')


a = pd.DataFrame(df_pca3d.groupby("labels")["Aid"].apply(lambda x: all(i in x.values for i in ("1", 
"3","5","7"))))
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    if points.xs != []:
        if a.iloc[int(points.trace_name.split(" ")[1])]["Aid"] == True:
            webbrowser.open('url')


fig.data[0].on_click(update_point)
fig.data[1].on_click(update_point)
fig.data[2].on_click(update_point)
fig.data[3].on_click(update_point)
fig.data[4].on_click(update_point)
fig.data[5].on_click(update_point)

fig.write_html("test.html")
```